# How to add sensor_msgs.msg type in my ros system?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, ros

I am working with **ROS Kinetic** on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B which contains Raspbian Stretch Lite. Well, when I create a package in a specific ws to make streaming video from Raspberry Pi to a Linux remote Pc I get an import error about the msg type named **sensor_msgs.msg**. When I run the same code on my linux pc, it works. But it is not works on the Raspberry Pi because of this error(**sensor_msgs.msg**).

I want to build a publisher on the raspberry pi using ros. What can I do to solve this error? I can't found this message type in my rosmsg list, when I use this command **$rosmsg list | grep sensor_msgs**.

This is my code scrip which is on the Raspberry Pi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg **import** Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    rospy.init_node('stream_video',anonymous=False)
    front_pub = rospy.Publisher('/image_front',Image,queue_size=1)
    rate = rospy.Rate(30)
    bridge = CvBridge()

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        try:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                img = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, 'bgr8')
                front_pub.publish(img)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
**pi@raspberrypi**:**~/selfdriving_ws/src/camera_stream/src $** rosrun camera_stream stream_video.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/selfdriving_ws/src/camera_stream/src/stream_video.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
**ImportError: No module named sensor_msgs.msg**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never run it on RPI. In normal PC, there wasn`t such issue. BTW there shouldnt be *

```
>>> from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
>>>
```

There could be several possible causes e.g  CMAKE file issue. sensor_msgs not installed/not compatible, config error etc

from your word " I can't found this message type in my rosmsg list, when I use this command $rosmsg list | grep sensor_msgs." I guess it because you didn`t install it or installed a non-compatible version.

Try to install using the wstools to get it. RPI require some special touch.

```
rosinstall_generator sensor_msgs --rosdistro indigo --deps -wet-only --tar > indigo-sensor_msgs-wet.rosinstall
wstool init src indigo-sensor_msgs-wet.rosinstall
```

Comment: Hey, im trying to install sensor_msg package in python, but I cant find it in pip.
you think you can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install ROS sensor message package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-sensor-msgs
```

For example, if you are using the Kinetic version of ROS:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-sensor-msgs
```

Then import it:

```
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
```